# Fetching an image file of .jpg format using @PathVariable annotation and the url pattern in *.do

Tags: spring

I want to load an image in jsp , I am calling the controller method for that.But I get an error saying "http://localhost:8080/SocialNetworkingApp/imageController/life.jpg.do  Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 406 (Not Acceptable)". I am using @PathVariable to fetch the image .

The following is my code :-

In the jsp I am using

```
<c:forEach items="${post.imageNames}" var="imageObj">
      <img src="/SocialNetworkingApp/imageController/${imageObj}.do" alt="image_post"/>
  </c:forEach>
```

In my controller , I am doing the request mapping as follows.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/imageController/{imageName}",produces = { MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE,MediaType.IMAGE_GIF_VALUE, MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE })
    @ResponseBody
    public Raster getImageForPost(@PathVariable String imageName){
        LOG.info("Entry :: getImageForPost"); 
        BufferedImage bufferedImageForPost = null;
        final org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders headers = new org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders();
        try{
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG);
            LOG.info("imageName-->"+imageName);
            File imageFromMongo = new File(IMAGE_FROM_PATH+imageName);
            GridFSDBFile imageFile=MongoUtility.getImageFileFromMongo(imageName);
            imageFile.writeTo(imageFromMongo);
            bufferedImageForPost=ImageIO.read(imageFromMongo);

        }
        catch(IOException e){
            LOG.error("Error :: while fetching image from the GridFs post",e);
        }

        LOG.info("Exit :: getImageForPost");
        return bufferedImageForPost.getData();
    }
```

In my web.xml , I am mapping my servlet to url-pattern *.do

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>socialDispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>socialDispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

The controller code for saving the image into a particular path is working fine,but at the time of sending the image file to the jsp,it is giving error.
I think it is excpecting *.jpg file it is gettinh *.jpg.do file.
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

**MultipartFile** is normally used to upload the file/images. Try to use that as shown below

```
@RequestMapping(value="/uploadfile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String uploadFile(
            @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file){
        String message = "";

        if (!file.isEmpty()) {
            try {                
                byte [] bytes = file.getBytes();                
                //logic to persist the file                
                message = "You successfully uploaded " + file.getName() + "!";
            } catch (Exception e) {
                message = "You failed to upload " + file.getName() + " => " + e.getMessage();
            }
        } else {
            message = "You failed to upload " + file.getName() + " because the file was empty.";
        }
        file = null;
        return message;
    }
```

Comment: Actually I think I have not communicated the question well. I am not facing issue in uploading file. 
I have saved the file in database(Mongo), now I have to fetch the image and display it in the jsp.
But the think is that ,there will be more than 1 image. So I want to fetch it on the fly .i.e I want to controller from src of the img tag

<c:forEach items="${post.imageNames}" var="imageObj">
      <img src="/SocialNetworkingApp/imageController/${imageObj}.do" alt="image_post"/>
  </c:forEach>  
  So that is why I have used like this. But some "Non acceptance error 406" is coming.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved,so I am posting my answer it may be helpful to others.
The issue was with the return type,instead of Raster ,the return type should be byte[] array.
By changing the return type to byte[] array it started working fine.